# How can I use javascript to scroll horizontally smoothly?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a horizontally structured website I'm making for a client here:

http://jules-photo.com/shhmgmt/

They are requesting that, upon loading, the page auto scrolls smoothly to the right until it reaches the end and stops.  Ideally I would like to have control of the speed of the scroll.  I feel like I've plugged in every bit of javascript I can find off the web but no luck.  Can anyone recommend a solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Update:

OK, so I think I found the code that I need using jQuery.ScrollTo:

```
$(...).scrollTo( { top:0, left:700},800 );
```

But I'm not exactly sure how to implement that into a jquery script so that it triggers when the page loads.  My jquery so far (which has been unsuccessful):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.scrollTo-min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// no conflict jquery
jQuery.noConflict();
//jquery stuff

$(document).ready(function(){

$(...).scrollTo( { top:0, left:700},800 );

});

</script>
```

UPDATE: I ended up using animate() like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: $("body").width()},11000) 
    $(window).bind("mousewheel", function(ev) { 
        $("html, body").stop(); 
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `animate()` 
Jquery doesn't have a built in slider control for horizontal slides, but below are some fiddles I found that hopefully point you in the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/rs2QK/ - This one slides panel open from the left and to close to the right

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/RZpbK/ - Panels slide open from left to right and close to the left befor opening the new one.

source:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a variety of scroll-related plugins in addition to it's excellent innate support for scrolling.

This site: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/ has a variety of excellent scrolling demos you may find useful.

I see you use mootools... Despite it also using the $ variable, you can use both in tandem using jQuery.noConflict().